# In R, is there any way to share a variable between difference processes of R in the same machine?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, shared-memory

My problem is that I have a large model, which is slow to load to memory. To test it on many samples, I need to run some C program to generating input features for model, then run R script to predict. It takes too much time to load the model every time.

So I am wondering

1) if there is some method to keep the model ( a variable in R) in the memory.

or

2) Can I run a separative process of R as a dedicated server, then all the prediction processes of R can access the variable in the server on the same machine.

The model is never changed during for all the prediction. It is a randomForest model stored in a .rdata file, which has ~500MB. Loading this model is slow.

I know that I can use parallel R (snow, doPar, etc) to perform prediction in parallel, however, this is not what I want, since it require me to change the data flow I used.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: "however, this is not what I want, since it will change the framework I am using." Could you explain what you mean?

Comment: My data flow for each sample is following. 
[1.computing the input features] -> [2.run R randomForest prediction] -> [3.another program to compute the final results from the output of R] . Since 1 and 3 are not coded in R, and not easy to be separated from the main program controlling the data flow. I expect there is a way to keep this data flow.

Comment: I tried Rserve/RSclient. Rserve can run R in a daemon mode. I am not sure if it makes use of multi-core when more than one client connected to a R server.

Answer (score 2):

If you are regenerating the model every time, you can save the model as an RData file and then share it across the different machines.   While it may still take time to load from disk to memory, it will save the time of regenerating.

```
   save(myModel, file="path/to/file.Rda")

   # then
   load(file="path/to/file.Rda")
```

**Edit per @VictorK's suggetsion:**
As Victor points out, since you are saving only a single object, `saveRDS` may be a better choice.

```
  saveRDS(myModel, file="path/to/file.Rds")

  myModel <- readRDS(file="path/to/file.Rds")
```

Comment: If you are saving just a single variable, `saveRDS` and `loadRDS` may be cleaner.

Comment: In particular, I am loading the randomForest model every time. The model file is about ~500MB. It will take about 3 minutes to load it from hard disk to memory. There is not much difference between loading it from a local hard disk, memory file system or a network file system. So I suppose the most time used in loading is about parsing the data other than reading the data from disk.

Comment: Unfortunately, saveRDS is not available on my R-2.15.1.